# make drawer layout some portion always visible in android

Tags: android, drawerlayout

I am using drawer layout to make a drawer that moves from right to left. But i want to make some portion of drawer to be always visible on right side. Please help me how can i do this.

Answer (score -1):

Hi i have fix this issue with some trick just set the same background of main Drawer layout which is set in your child layout .